# Customizing micro cloud foundry?

Tags: cloud-foundry

I am trying to create a stand alone companion to a customized cloud foundry deployment that has some additional services enabled in it, in the same way that micro cloud foundry is a companion to cloudfoundry.com.  I've [blogged a longer description](http://corneliadavis.com/blog/2012/11/29/customizing-micro-cloud-foundry/) of my work to date for context but the short question is this:

Is there micro-cf-release available which can be extended and used to create a customized micro cloud foundry?  With the [release train](http://blog.cloudfoundry.com/2012/11/08/new-release-of-micro-cloud-foundry/) happening now, this must be somewhere, along with a process and tooling for creating the VM.  Is this in the opensource somewhere?

Answer (score 3):

The capistrano script that builds the releases is:

https://github.com/cloudfoundry/micro/blob/master/build/build.cap

This workflow is experimental, but it should be possible to use a subset of the build task in the script and customize cf-release before building from it.

Comment: Okay, that helps.  But isn't there a "mcf-release" somewhere that I could customize instead of starting from the cf-release?